# How to visualize the text analysis using CNN and tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, text, visualization, conv-neural-network

I am new to tensorflow, I am using CNN model descrined by  http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/

I am getting around 60% accuracy for 5 class and 80% accuracy for 2 class classification

Now I want to visualize which word impact most to a particular classification, can anybody tell me how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Don't have much experience either, but I found a way to detect useful features for the training stage:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/machine-learning/ml-on-structured-data-analysis-prep-1

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to have a look at the [LIME framework](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime):

> Marco Tulio Ribeiro, Sameer Singh, Carlos Guestrin: ["Why Should I Trust You?": Explaining the Predictions of Any Classifier](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04938). 2016.

It also has [a youtube video explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hUnRCxnydCc).

The very gist / simplified extremely:

1. Make the normal prediction
2. Remove some words. Make more predictions.
3. Look at the change in prediction. If the prediction changes more, the word was more important.

Comment: thanks Martin for sharing this, but I hoped some approach in tensor flow, and using neural network